# Best resources to learn about Best Practice Scaling of IT Architecture

Tags: untagged

Looking for resources to learn the best practices and basics of scaling a backend infrastructure for an application or a web app. I am interested in Amazon Web Services and really enjoy architecting technical solutions. Is there a book / blog / website I can start? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of applications - homebrew, or commercial/oss? What platform(s)? How many interactions does the app have (database, storage, network, etc)? What you're asking for is a huge area, and one that every vendor will approach differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not read these myself but I have heard that the books [Web Operations: Keeping the Data On Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449377440) and [The Art of Capacity Planning: Scaling Web Resources](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518579) should be pretty good . Chapters include "How cloud services such as EC2 can fit into a capacity strategy" in The Art of Capacity Planning.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in AWS, reading the VP of AWS's blog might be good: http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/